How to avoid workstation suspend if monitor is turned off
[Edit: after a reboot, the "Never shut down the computer or let it go to sleep" special behaviour in the system settings seems to be working]
I have a workstation/server running Kubuntu 22.04. I notice that if I turn off the monitor (via the physical button on the monitor), after a while the workstation goes into suspend. The same happens if the monitor is unplugged from the workstation. This does not happen if the monitor is on instead – even when the display goes off after a while because of power management.
I notice the suspend status because the workstation/server doesn't let me log in via SSH and doesn't respond to pings. Also, as soon as I turn the monitor on again and move the mouse I see the typical screen of resuming from suspend.
In the user settings/power management,  the "suspend session" button is unticked. This phenomenon still happens. So Under "Activity settings" I selected "Define a special behaviour" and "Never shut down the computer or let it go to sleep". Yet this suspend on monitor-off still happens.
What kind of settings should I change in order to avoid this? Can this be considered a bug? If so, is it Ubuntu/Kubuntu-dependent?

how do you know that the workstation is entering suspend status when you power off the monitor?

@jsotola Indeed, sorry for omitting that information. I edited my question, which seems to be solved now.

You can completely disable suspend with
systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target

But I'm thinking the monitor being on or off is coincidental, as I've had systems unexpectedly suspend even without that.
I believe this is an intentional feature that is independent from the settings in the GUI.
